# Question concerning assigning a new value to the member variable of a class element in the list

Tags: python, list, class

Assign a new value to the member variable of a class element in the list. Why do all the member variable values of the class elements in the list change? As you can see, I only changed the value of the member variable of `Li [0]` , but the value of the member variable of all elements in `Li` changed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrDiy.jpg)

How can I only change the single element in the list (example: `li[0]`) instead all of them?

Comment: Post code as text, not images. The goal is a running script we can copy and reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List multiplication just adds references to its existing values. A list has no way of knowing how its objects are constructed and certainly can't make new ones. You could try `li =[A(2) for _ in range(3)]` to construct your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot! likes from a green hand